# Slide-down tabs not working as expected

Tags: jquery, tabs, slidedown

I have made a custom based tabs using jQuery. The rule is that once you click a tab it will slide down the content with `fadeIn` effect. If you click another tab then it will not `slideUp`, rather it will show the content from tab 2 with `fadeIn` effect. If you click tab 2 again (which is already opened ) then the tab container will slide up.

It works for the first time but if you click the same tab again (after sliding up) then it takes some time to slide down which is not smooth as well.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tabs .col-3 a').click(function(e) { // Or bind to any other event you like, or call manually

      e.preventDefault();
      var hrefid = $(this).attr("href");
      var tabid = ($(this).attr("href")).replace('#', ''); // remove #         

      var getContent = $(hrefid).html();

      $('#maintabcontent').hide().html(getContent).fadeIn(1400);


      $('span.plus').text("+");
      var $t = $('.tab-container');

      if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).find('span').text("+");
        $t.slideUp(function() {
          $('#maintabcontent').html('');
        });
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
      } else {

        $(this).find('span').text("-");
        $t.slideDown(600, function() {

        });
        if ($t.is(':visible')) {
          $('.col-3').removeClass('active');
          $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
      }

    });

  });
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.full-width {
  background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1220px;
}
.padding-top-bottom-small {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 403px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 32.5%;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-container {
  background: #505050 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1220px;
}
.padding-top-bottom-big {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-width container tabs">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small"> <a href="#tab-1"><h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span></h3></a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small"> <a href="#tab-2"><h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span></h3></a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small"> <a href="#tab-3"><h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span></h3></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="main-container padding-top-bottom-big" id="maintabcontent"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">Tab Content 1</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Tab Content 2</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Tab Content 3</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/5dtLo6sr/1/)

Comment: Thanks @showdev for the correction. Also please let me know how can I create 'Run code snippet' thing

Comment: This might be helpful: [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: ahh...I will take a look now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **[`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)** before `fadeIn()`:

```
$('#maintabcontent').hide().html(getContent).stop().fadeIn(1400);
```

That will stop any running animations and prevent the jerkiness you're experiencing.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkevxgd2/)

Comment: Simply brilliant. I never thought in that way. Thanks a lot for your help. I was pulling my hair for last 2 hours. Thanks once again.

Comment: One more question. According to the pattern of the coding do you think any improvisation I can do here. I mean any suggestion if you think I am lacking something in this code.

Comment: Your code is pretty clean as-is.  Probably don't need to set the html in `slideUp()`.  You could simply do `$t.slideUp();` and `$t.slideDown(600);`.

Comment: Actually don't know why I felt that when sliding up, the div needs to clear the content and used $('#maintabcontent').html(''); inside slideUp function. Will it effect in the performance?